# Why my nav bar doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in bootstrap.
I'm trying to configure my  menu bar. I added this line of code into my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

After that, I added this block of code in my view:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Inicio <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Opcion 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Opcion 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Opcion 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Pagina 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pagina 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is what I want:
[image]

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

I want all items horizontally, not vertically...
Maybe this is very basic, but this is the first time that I'm using bootstrap.
Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few things in your code

See a basic demo from bootstrap itself [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)

Take a look at [navbar docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Here is a simple working snippet base on your code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Inicio <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Opcion 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Opcion 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Opcion 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Pagina 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Pagina 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```